Issue with using Gemini AI API
I have a Python script which creates a local chatbot server on my PC and is trying to use Google Gemini AI via my API.
Here are the details:
# Trying to access Gogle Gemini AI via my API:
base_url = "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/"
model = "gemini-1.5-flash"
task = "generateContent"
endpoint = ".apps.googleusercontent.com"
google_client_id = "{GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}"  # Stored in a variable declared and set at startup
# Constructing the URL
url = f"{base_url}{model}:{task}?key={GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}{endpoint}"

The above url is correctly constructed, but I still get an error message:

Gemini API Error: 401 Client Error: # Unauthorized for {see the above url}

I am running my script in PowerShell on my local PC. All imports have been made.
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect
import asyncio
import json
import requests
import webbrowser
import uvicorn
import threading
import websockets
import os
import google.generativeai as genai

...
I have also tried with Vertex AI, but that is even more complicated and didn't give any results.

Google Client ID and Google Gemini API key are two separate things. Both are needed here.

I can see you are trying to make the api call instead of using the sdk which you have already imported. If that is the case I see no reason for you to include the endpoint variable as it is not relevant in making the api call. Also the api call accepts the API key for gemini which I hope is what you mean by GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
# Trying to access Google Gemini AI via my API:
base_url = "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/"
model = "gemini-1.5-flash"
task = "generateContent"
google_client_id = "{GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}"  # Stored in a variable declared and set at startup
# Constructing the URL
url = f"{base_url}{model}:{task}?key={GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}"


Thank you for your contribution. It would be helpful if you could improve this answer with an actual solution with working code.
